# Why wont Mongo C# Driver Reregister the class map?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I needed to update my `BsonClassMap` definition and have the following

```
if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Order)))
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Order>(cm =>
                {
                    //do some stuff with property serialization
                });


}
```

The problem I am having is that the class map is always registered. I can't remove the if statement, or it will complain that the class map is always registered.

How am I supposed to do what I need to do on the class map? Is there a way to unregister and reregister? Or is there a way to update the registered class map directly?

I am fine with 'restarting' the client or needing to reregister class map, but I can't seem to accomplish this.

How can I get the classmap to reregister? I only need to do this so that the new property serialization rules will take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C# reference:

> It is very important that the registration of class maps occur prior
>   to them being needed. The best place to register them is at app
>   startup prior to initializing a connection with MongoDB.

As far as I know, you would have to restart the client and register the new class map **before** initializing the connection in order to register/update the class map.